problem with calling function in next js when i want upload file(undefided Error)
I have a problem with calling a function that uploads a file. In the ImportFile component, the file is read properly, and errors are caught on the client side. However, when I try to check what is happening on the server side, nothing is printed. Where could the problem be in invoking that function?
'use client'
import { uploadFile } from "@/api/client";
import { useState } from "react";

function ImportFile() {

    const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const handleFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.target.files) {
            setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (file === null) {
            return setError('Pick the file');
        }

        try {
            await uploadFile(file);
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.error("throw undefided error", error);
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                setError(error.message);
            }
        }
    }

    return(
        <div className="items-center justify-center w-full">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="dropzone-file" className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-bray-800 dark:bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:border-gray-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
                <svg className="w-8 h-8 mb-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
                <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2"/>
                </svg>
                <p className="mb-2 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><span className="font-semibold">Click to upload</span> or drag and drop</p>
                <p className="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">CSV or JSON file</p>
                </div>
            <input id="dropzone-file" type="file" className="hidden" onChange={handleFileChange}/>
            </label>
            <button type="submit" className="text-center w-full bg-emerald-700 rounded">Upload Clients</button>
            </form>
        </div> 
    );
}

export default ImportFile

'use server'
export const uploadFile = async (file: File) => {
    console.log("it doesnt print anything");
    try {
        console.log('it doesnt print anything');
        const cookie = cookies().get('jwt')?.value;
        if (cookie === null) {
            redirect('/login');
        }

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);
        

        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/uploadFile', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookie}`,
            'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            body: formData,
        });
    
        if (!response.ok) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                redirect('/login');
            } else if (response.status === 400) {
                const errorMessage = await response.json();
                let message = "";
                Object.entries(errorMessage).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                    message += key + ": " + value + "\n";
                })
                throw new Error(message);
            } else {
                throw new Error("Server cannot handle request");
            }
        }
  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("it doesnt print anything");
      throw error;
    }
}

Someone has the same problem?

The function is not invoking properly. Could you please share the code with codesandbox?

Ok, i found solution. Just send formdata to uploadFile.ts, because File doesnt handle
